# Pick files with specific filenames in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-blob-storage

I am looking to copy files from blob storage to another blob using Azure Data Factory. However I want to pick only files which starts with say AAABBBCCC , XXXYYYZZZ and MMMNNNOOO. And the remaining I would like to ignore.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `prefix` to pick the files that you want to copy. And this [sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/data-factory-copy-blob-to-blob) shows how to copy blob to blob using Azure Data Factory.

`prefix`: Specifies a string that filters the results to return only blobs whose name begins with the specified prefix.

```
// List blobs start with "AAABBBCCC" in the container
await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in client.GetBlobsAsync(prefix: "AAABBBCCC"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(blobItem.Name);
}
```

**With ADF setting:**

Set `Wildcard paths` with `AAABBBCCC*`. For more details, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#source-transformation).

[image]

Comment: Do I need to write c# code for this. I was looking for a configuration setting in ADF itself.

Answer (score 0):

In ADF, use the Copy Activity and the wildcard path to set your matching file patterns

[image]

Comment: I tried the same , however I am looking to add multiple file patterns may be around 3 file patterns . In the current case , I am able to give only 1 file pattern. So I am forced to change my file pattern everytime .